# How to separate out nested json values in pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have data in Pandas dataframe where certain fields have nested JSONs in them:

[image: Sample Data]

As visible in the sample data, the `post_likes` field has nested JSON and is sometimes blank as well. `post_shares` has JSON format, but just one value and it is sometimes 0.

How can I grab data out of JSON objects inside the fields? In the case of `post_likes`, I want to create a separate field for each object in JSON nest.

I tried using `pd.series()` but getting Key and Runtime errors.